# How to access data from a JSON output

Tags: json, object

Following is the result of JSON.stringify()

```
{
  "requestId": "40291967-329b-4555-95c4-ff6d2f8bda3c",
  "metadata": {
    "width": 2096,
    "height": 4132,
    "format": "Jpeg"
  },
  "result": {
    "landmarks": [
      {
        "name": "Space Needle",
        "confidence": 0.9998178
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to access name attribute so is it done ?

Comment: What language? How do you want to access it? Do you want to deserialize it into an object, or just access a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.stringify() turns your object into a string so you'd need to parse the string looking for entities within the JSON object. A better way to do it would be to access the object before you pass it to stringify.

JSON.parse() will convert the string back into a json object so that you can access its members.

in your case

`yourObject.result.landmarks[0].name`

Comment: Great! Choose this as an answer if it addresses your question. Thanks